# Python wrong output without using csv module and defaultdict

Tags: python, output

I am reading and printing out the text from .CSV file. I am struggling to get it to work. Any help would be great.

```
def readWordFile(fileName):
    for line in fileName:
        text = line.split(', ')
        word = text[0]
        newYearCount = createYearCount(int(text[1]), int(text[2]))
        result = {}
        if line not in result:
            result[word] = [newYearCount]
        else:
            result[word].append(newYearCount)
        print(result)

def main():
    fileName = input('Enter filename: ')
    readWordFile(open(fileName))

main()
```

I have to read in a csv file which represents a word, the year, and the occurrences of that word in that year:

```
airport, 2007, 175702
airport, 2008, 173294
request, 2005, 646179
request, 2006, 677820
request, 2007, 697645
request, 2008, 795265
wandered, 2005, 83769
wandered, 2006, 87688
wandered, 2007, 108634
wandered, 2008, 171015
```

My current readWordFile function output looks like:

```
{'airport': [YearCount( year=2007, count=175702 )]}
{'airport': [YearCount( year=2008, count=173294 )]}
{'request': [YearCount( year=2005, count=646179 )]}
{'request': [YearCount( year=2006, count=677820 )]}
{'request': [YearCount( year=2007, count=697645 )]}
{'request': [YearCount( year=2008, count=795265 )]}
{'wandered': [YearCount( year=2005, count=83769 )]}
{'wandered': [YearCount( year=2006, count=87688 )]}
{'wandered': [YearCount( year=2007, count=108634 )]}
{'wandered': [YearCount( year=2008, count=171015 )]}
```

What I am trying to do is trying to print the correct output, look below.

```
{
    ’airport’: [
        YearCount( year=2007, count=175702 ),
        YearCount( year=2008, count=173294 )
    ],
    ’wandered’: [
        YearCount( year=2005, count=83769 ),
        YearCount( year=2006, count=87688 ),
        YearCount( year=2007, count=108634 ),
        YearCount( year=2008, count=171015 )
    ],
    ’request’: [
        YearCount( year=2005, count=646179 ),
        YearCount( year=2006, count=677820 ),
        YearCount( year=2007, count=697645 ),
        YearCount( year=2008, count=795265 )
    ]
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) standard module and a defaultdict.

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a [*new question*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (or better yet, search for the answer, because I'm sure it's been answered before). Don't edit this question to become a new one entirely--that just makes the existing answer invalid for the new question, and the whole thing becomes confusing and useless to future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)

csv_reader = csv.reader(fileName)

for row in csv_reader:
    result[row[0]].append(createYearCount(int(row[1]), int(row[2]))

print result
```

Comment: it works, however, I am getting this thing at the beginning of the output. `defaultdict(<class 'list'>, ` Please look at the OP for update.

Comment: I don't see anything new in your OP.

Comment: @user3385538 If you want a plain dict to print out at the end, you can do `print(dict(result))`. But it would be better to just format the output yourself, because formatting should generally be kept separate from changing actual content.